# Instance disappears when animates

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, animation

I have made a MovieClip and attached it to the below code.When i test the movie and i have already placed an instance on stage it works fine.When i instantiate the object through code and add it to stage it disappears when i click it.I work in flash.

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

import com.greensock.*; 

public class Card6 extends MovieClip {

    public function Card6( )        {
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Enter);
    }
    private function Enter( ev : MouseEvent ) {
        TweenMax.to(this, 0.25,  { rotationY: 180 }  );
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code where i instantiate the MovieClip from the library,Card6 is the base Class.

```
var photo: MovieClip = new PhotoB( );
photo.x = 100;
photo.y = 300;
stage.addChild(photo);
```

UPDATE :
I succeed to make it work i don't know how since i didn't changed the code a bit.The problem is i don't know what is the solution and i encounter the same problem in other examples.
This is the code i used in the first frame and worked.

```
var sp : DisplayObject = new border( ); //<-- Different name,same Object
addChild(sp);
sp.x = 400;
sp.y = 300;
```

And this is the code i used for the Main Class

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class DocumentH extends MovieClip {

    public function DocumentH( )    {
    var sp : MovieClip = new border( );
    addChild(sp);
    sp.x = 400;
    sp.y = 300;
    }
  }
}
```

I can't tell what made the diferrence and worked.I try to do the exactly same thing in another fla and failed.In library i have only one square which a have convert it to MovieClip.
(Here is a link with the fla http://www65.zippyshare.com/v/65975812/file.html). I use Flash CS4 Pro

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it has something to do with the 3d transformation center point - when you add it to the stage these are set to the center of the object in question. Try setting `z = 0` before you do `addChild()`, to initialize the 3d matrix, and see if it disappears instantly then as well.

If it does, you might need to look at where the 0-point in the movieclip is, or maybe even do 3d transforms on it instead of regular x,y ones.

EDIT:
It's hard to figure out exactly what needs to be done without more information on how your library item looks, but try translating the 3d matrix opposite the way you are moving it, eg `photo.transform.matrix3D.appendTranslation(-100, -300, 0);` after your movement. Also try setting all your positions to 0, and make the flash player window larger, so you can see your object. This should give you some hint of what is going on :)

Comment: I don't know somehow i managed to get this work without change the code a bit,but the problem still remains when i use the code in a main class.The object  disappears.

Comment: Peculiar problem. Try moving your code in the class over to a function that is called when the clip is added to stage instead (this is a shot in the dark however). Like so; `addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageListener)`.

Comment: I didn't have to add the listener everything works now.I don't know how,i changed `stage.addChild` to `addChild` maybe was that.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your duration to something like 5 seconds so you can see it tweening.

Comment: The problem is it disappears when i click the object and the animation activate,has nothing to do with duration i've tried.When i place an instance on stage before testing the movie it works properly,and now i don't know how it works even when i place the initialization code inside the first frame,but when i use a Document class to do the same thing it fails,have the same problem.

Comment: Of course it has nothing to do with the duration. My point was to slow the duration down enough so you can see it going poof. My thoughts on this is it is disappearing because your tween is causing it to go off screen. Slowing it down would allow you to see that. ".25" in all aspects is an instant tween and you probably would not even be able to make out whats going on. This wasn't an answer per-say but more of a way to help you diagnose it. But I guess you figured it out so its all good anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry this problem trouble me a lot and made me act recklessly.I solve the problem but still I am unable to figure out what was the cause.Someone assume that I place it out of view that's why it's disappear when I act on 3d dimension.

Comment: Exactly, That is the reason I told you to slow the duration down so you can see it.

Comment: If i remove the tween and just specify the rotationY of the Object it doesn't appear at all.

Comment: Of course because it is moved out of site instantly. Put the tween back in and change the duration of the tween to 10 and then try it.

Comment: As i told it disappears instantly.The only change i make and work is to change the `stage.addChild` to `addChild`.Why it's so obvious that it goes out of site?